# How do we change the context path of atlasmap-2.1.6?

Tags: java, reactjs, react-router, atlasmap

github atlasmap 2.1.6 (https://github.com/atlasmap/atlasmap/tree/atlasmap-2.1.6)

addded   server.servlet.context-path: /test but UI not rendering properly

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q74F.png)

Comment: Have you ever figure out how to make this work?